# Fixed scrollbar position

Tags: html, wordpress, scrollbar

I use this code inside my wordpress website to display a page from a different website.

```
<div><object style="overflow: hidden; border: 2px ridge black;" data="http://www.wijzeringeldzaken.nl/direct-hulp/rekenhulpen/bereken-hoeveel-je-moet-verdienen-om-een-huis-te-kopen.aspx" type="text/html" width="900px" height="440px">    </object></div>
```

The page shows up just fine, but i would like to set its scrollbars (Both the horizontal as vertical) to a fixed position, so that the right part of the page displays.

Ideal would be to be able to also hide the scrollbars but for now, being able to give a offset with the scrollbars would be awesome.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Cheers,

Laurens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery for a quick fix, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_scrolltop_set) is how to do it.

However, it is easier with pure Javascript. :)

```
document.getElementById("YOURDIVHERE").scrollTop = AMOUNT;
```

Change YOURDIVHERE and AMOUNT as you wish.